# Sitecore Image Field Source to filter on template type

Tags: datasource

Is it possible to set the source of an image field so it filters on a specified template name. so only showing these images to be associated with the item

Tried various ways from the following link

http://zacharykniebel.com/blog/sitecore/2014/june/26/constraining-the-sitecore-7-multilist-and-treelist-fields-with-and-without-search

Answer (score 2):

Image fields does not support data source query, and it is not possible to extend this filed type to support the functionality that you want.

Associating images to items based on the image template is maybe not a good idea. In Sitecore all images (of same file type) will get the same template when you upload an image. I think it would be better to associate images to content items based on their location in the media library.

It is possible to [extend the image field type to support a query that dynamically set the root folder as described in this blog post](https://acetechpro.wordpress.com/2015/11/01/using-sitecore-image-field-treelist-with-images-in-a-multisite-instance/). Maybe that can be helpful in your situation.

Comment: the worpress page was deleted